# Unable to render error page in ejs using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I want the class to be activated when the path === '/' else ''.I used ternary operator to activate the class. the class is in active state when the path is equal but when the path is not equal it is unable to render the error page that i given

```
<header class="main-header">
    <nav class="main-header__nav">
        <ul class="main-header__item-list">
            <li class="main-header__item"><a class="<%= path === '/' ? 'active' : '' %>" href="/">Shop</a></li>
            <li class="main-header__item"><a class="<%= path === '/admin/add-product' ? 'active' : '' %>" href="/admin/add-product">Add Product</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

the code runs fine if it is equal to the path but if it is not equal that when i want to render a error page

[check this image for error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGxJc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, omit the `.ejs` in your include statements:

```
<%- include('includes/navigation') %>

<%- include('includes/end') %>
```

Next, on your app.js, you will need to pass the path as *context* to the view:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const path = '/';
  res.render('somePage', {path:path});    
});

app.get('/admin/add-product', function(req, res) {
  const path = '/admin/add-product';
  res.render('somePage', {path:path});    
});
```

Now, you shouldn't get the 'path is not defined' error.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks it is working after giving path to 404 error page